# DeprecationWarning: Compilation.assets will be frozen in future, all modifications are deprecated

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I am working on a react project and when I updated webpack 4.44.2 to 5.4.0 I am getting the following message:

```
[DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_ASSETS] DeprecationWarning: Compilation.assets will be frozen in future, all modifications are deprecated.
BREAKING CHANGE: No more changes should happen to Compilation.assets after sealing the Compilation.
    Do changes to assets earlier, e. g. in Compilation.hooks.processAssets.
    Make sure to select an appropriate stage from Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_*.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I searched a lot but did not get an exact answer. So how can I solve ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*Update 2021, Feb 25*

Html-webpack-plugin v5 is released, just run

```
npm i -D html-webpack-plugin@latest
```

or

```sh
npm uninstall html-webpack-plugin

npm i -D html-webpack-plugin
```

---

*Original answer*

This is mostly related to html-webpack-plugin, and while its new version 5 (integrated with webpack v5) is still in beta, you should update it manually:

```sh
npm show html-webpack-plugin version 
4.5.1

npm show html-webpack-plugin@next version
5.0.0-beta.5

npm i -D html-webpack-plugin@next
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer ! Thank you

Comment: I found this too, but it didn't fix it for me.

Comment: this issue can happen not only for html-webpack-plugin, for me it was for brotli-webpack-plugin

Comment: As per comment by Oleh, this can happen due to other plugins, For me it was the copy-webpack-plugin.

Answer (score 11):

Are you running command like `npx webpack`? If so, you can use:

```
$ node --trace-deprecation ./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

It should show you all those webpack plugins producing those warnings.

Comment: In my case I had to use tracing this way `node --trace-deprecation ./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js` (Im running webpack using package.json `scripts` via `npn run build`)

Answer (score 3):

These depraction warnings are negligible. The root case are plugins which violate the quite new Webpack 5 specs. Someday they will swing together (for a while).

You can get arround of `[DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_ASSETS]` by updating npm packages. Check the latest versions with:

```
npm outdated
```

That worked for me, but now I get `[DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_OPTIMIZE_CHUNK_ASSETS]`. Just wait and see.

Comment: Works fine, just run `npm update` (or `npm update --force` if you must) afterward